# OSM Address suggestion service

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding

For geocoding we are using the Nominatim

from the below URL
    http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/
But i need to implement suggestion on the address, do OSM has this service like Google and ESRI

is their any other method to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a little similar to the suggestions

from geoName server which is open data

http://api.geonames.org/search?q=london&maxRows=10&style=SHORT&lang=es&username=demo

By changing the style=SHORT parameter we can just get the names with lat long

more on Geoname server here

http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html

Answer (score 2):

No, currently Nominatim doesn't support suggestions but this feature is on the todo list. As Nominatim is [open source](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim) you are welcome to help implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

[Photon](https://github.com/komoot/photon) by [komoot](http://www.komoot.de/) is a more modern search engine which supports suggestions. Also, [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) can help to some extent (can suggest street names if you know the exact city name). There was also [imposm-geocoder](https://bitbucket.org/quiqua/imposm.geocoder/src) project, but it seems to be dead.

Comment: Anybody experience on that solutions? Sounds interesting :)

Comment: i found geoname server which is helpful